# Separating the lists elements to into separate numbers and writing into the notepad file

Tags: python

I have a two Python lists like this :

```
A= ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
B= ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

I want to rearrange it as shown below.

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

The output will be written into a notepad file and each element of the row will be separated by a space.
How can I do that in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `' '.join()` to join your list with a space. and '\n' to do line break

try this:

```
A= ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'] # your lists
B= ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
f = open("filename.txt","w+") # create your file
f.write(' '.join(A)) # write list A to your file
f.write('\n') # line break
f.write(' '.join(B)) # write list B to your file
```

filename.txt:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `join` to join the list elements with a space. Use '\n' for the line separater.

Try this code:

```
A= ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
B= ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']

with open('data.txt','w') as f:
   f.write(' '.join(A) + '\n' +  ' '.join(B))
```

Output (data.txt)

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

---- Update ----

If you want to write the lists multiple times, python provides string multiplication:  `mystring*5` will write `mystring` 5 times.

Try this code change:

```
n = 3
with open('data.txt','w') as f:
   f.write((' '.join(A)+'\n')*n + (' '.join(B)+'\n')*n)  # write each string n times
```

Output (data.txt)

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
6 7 8 9 10
6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and what if I want to repeat the entries in row A or/and row B, N number of times? For examples, if I want to repeat  1 2 3 4 5 on the 5 rows in the text file and then 6 7 8 9 10 in the next 5 rows in the text file?

Comment: Python has a quick method for that. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you Mike67. :) That is exactly what I was looking for.